# Objects with const data members as members of classes

Tags: c++, object

So I am trying to write a class called undergraduate that takes an object of the Phone class as an argument. However, the phone class uses a const data member called msg. This will not compile because of the const data member in the phone class. How do I fix it? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

//Below is my default constructor for the Phone class, it uses const data member msg

```
Phone::Phone():msg(10){ //intialize const data member

    areacode = 999;

    exchange = 999;

    line = 9999;
}
```

//here is my constructor that takes objects as arguments

```
Undergraduate::Undergraduate(Name sname, Date bday, Program sprogram, Phone sphone, char g, string s, int c, double G, int gdyr, string term){

    name = sname;
    date = bday;
    pgm = sprogram;
    phone = sphone;

    gender = g;
    status = s;
    credit = c;
    gpa = G;
    gradyear = gdyr;
    gradterm = term;
}
```

Comment: Im pretty new here, sorry! The language is c++

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here may be that you are saying phone = sphone; which would require changing the const member.  You can use an initializer list in the Undergraduate class to initialize it.

```
Undergraduate::Undergraduate(Name sname, Date bday, Program sprogram, Phone sphone, char g, string s, int c, double G, int gdyr, string term)
: phone(sphone)
{

    name = sname;
    date = bday;
    pgm = sprogram;

    gender = g;
    status = s;
    credit = c;
    gpa = G;
    gradyear = gdyr;
    gradterm = term;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I compiled this, my program stated that I have multiple undefined references to all of my objects, is there anything else I should do?